# Android Studio ClassLoader gives me Service Unknown Path

Tags: android, android-intent, service, classloader, android-studio-2.2

I'm having trouble to figure out how to properly run a service on Android Studio. I already tried to disable Instant Run, to name the service with the complete package name, but I keep getting this warning on run ou debug mode:

```
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.albertowd.myapplication-1/lib/arm
```

or if I use an emulator

```
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.albertowd.myapplication-1/lib/x86_64
```

And despite the program start with no errors, my intent to the server is never found:

```
W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.example.albertowd.myapplication/.MyService } U=0: not found
```

The manifest is right, I've created the service with the Service Wizard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.albertowd.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the intent is created on the MainActivity class:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
MainActivity.super.startService(intent);
```

I don't know what else I can do. I'm running Android Studio 2.2.1 with Oracle JDK 1.8 on Windows 10 x64, Ubuntu 16.04 x64 and Kubuntu 10.10 x64, all platforms have the same problem and I formatted them to be sure that was not an older version of anything in the way...

Comment: try removing `android:enabled="false"`

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But I'm wondering why is this an option?
`Whether or not the service can be instantiated by the system — "true" if it can be, and "false" if not. The default value is "true".`
Can I change that option in runtime?

Comment: I am not sure why it exists, maybe for letting you disable it without deleting those 4 lines or commenting them out :P And no you probably can't change it at runtime as its in XML and its only readable in most cases